# Java- Running Jar file through a batch file from a program

Tags: java, file, batch-file, jar

My problem is that whenever I go to run my code, inside the batch file it reads: `Error: Unable to access jarfile (Jarfile)` But when I run the batch file manually (clicking on it) it runs just fine.

Here is what the batch file reads:

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar JSonSign.jar nogui.
```

Here is what my Java program reads:

```
package com.Kaelinator;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ServerManager {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {
            System.out.println("Opening");
            Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process process = runTime.exec("cmd /C start /min " + "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/rekt/Run.bat");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Closing");
            process.destroy();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Specify full file paths.

Comment: @Noodles for the batch file or the program? The batch file is in the same folder with the jar file, if that helps.

Comment: Everywhere. By not doing you a taking on system configuration issues, relying on various search algorithms, which may or maynot find it depending, usually on what the current directory and when running as another user paths can be different.

Comment: @Noodles so you're saying instead of having just "java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar JSonSign.jar nogui.", I should have it more like "java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/rekt/JSonSign.jar nogui."?

Comment: Exactly. If the batch file is in the same directory you can use `%~dp0\JSonSign.jar` as `%~dp0` contain the batch file folder. See `set /?` for what it means.

Comment: @Noodles Ok, thank you so much, I'll try this!